Where can I find more information on the Single-Tone Extraction Algorithm that NI has available
I want to get more information on the National Instrument Tool called, Single Tone Extraction. Their forum has an article that is about a two minute read. It has a definition and two equations. Is there anywhere I can find information on an conceptual level?
Here is the link to NI's documentation.
https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview-api-ref/page/vi-lib/measure/matone-llb/extract-single-tone-information-vi.html
